# Where to host selenium python scripts online?

Tags: python, selenium, cloud, web-hosting, vps

I have to make a choice and I would like some advice please..

I have a python selenium script that opens browsers (with addons), visits pages, clicks..

I would like to have several versions of this script running 24/7,

where do you advise me to host it online ? I couldn't find much certain informations about how 
to setup a webdriver in Google cloud, apparently it would work on Amazon web services..

but I guess there are plenty of other options!
What's the best one?

thank you very much!
Tim

Comment: You can containerize and run any where that you like or available.

Comment: thank you for you answser. You mean I should use docker? Could you give me some details on what I should do concretely if you have some minutes, because I'm a total beginner....:)